# Webvtt in PHP file

Tags: php

How can i load webvtt in php file? Something like:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: ???; charset=ISO-8859-1");

WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:01.000
vM7nH0Kl-120.jpg#xywh=0,0,120,50

00:00.000 --> 00:02.000
vM7nH0Kl-120.jpg#xywh=120,0,120,50

00:00.000 --> 00:03.000
vM7nH0Kl-120.jpg#xywh=240,0,120,50

00:00.000 --> 00:04.000
vM7nH0Kl-120.jpg#xywh=360,0,120,50

?>
```

Comment: Your question is not explanatory ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `text/vtt` see : http://dev.w3.org/html5/webvtt/#the-webvtt-file-format

```
header("Content-Type:text/vtt;charset=utf-8");
```